# Why won't these constraints in a RelativeLayout work on a Xamarin Forms project?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Test.Views" x:Class="Test.Views.MainPage">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <BoxView Color="Yellow" HeightRequest="25" VerticalOptions="Start"></BoxView>
        <RelativeLayout x:Name="mainView" BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <BoxView x:Name="boxA" Color="Blue" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding BoxAXConstraint}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding BoxAYConstraint}">
            </BoxView>
            <BoxView x:Name="boxB" Color="Green" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding BoxBXConstraint}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding BoxBYConstraint}">
            </BoxView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I couldn't find a way to specify the bottom right corner in a relative layout in XAML, that's why I'm binding those constraints to properties in the code-behind like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public Constraint BoxAXConstraint { get; set; }
    public Constraint BoxAYConstraint { get; set; }
    public Constraint BoxBXConstraint { get; set; }
    public Constraint BoxBYConstraint { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BoxAXConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => mainView.Width - boxA.WidthRequest);
        BoxAYConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => 0);
        BoxBXConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => mainView.Width - boxB.WidthRequest);
        BoxBYConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => mainView.Height - boxB.HeightRequest);

        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

This is a [test project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5wlwam8bvk4ba6/test.zip?dl=0) that reproduces the issue on both Android and iOS.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it is a bug with a test project, post it as an issue on the Xamarin.Forms repo : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout has limitations on what can be expressed in XAML - you can't reference layout properties of two different elements in the same constraint, for instance.  You can definitely express more in C#.  In this case, you should be able to do things almost equivalently in XAML:

```
        <BoxView x:Name="boxB" Color="Green" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-50}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-50}">
        </BoxView>
```

The downside of the XAML approach is that if you change the WidthRequest or HeightRequest, you also need to change the constraints, whereas in the C# version, the changes are automatically taken into account because of the way the constraints are defined.

You could look into AbsoluteLayout, which (unlike RelativeLayout) attempts to keep elements on the screen.  So you can position a child of an AbsoluteLayout to be in the bottom right corner fairly easily in XAML:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,-1,-1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
```

Comment: The code I posted is a stripped down version of my actual layout. In my layout I also add some padding to the two small boxes that depend on their dimensions, and have a third box that is next to the left side of the small box at the top right corner, so its position depends on the dimensions of the box to the top right corner. Thats's why I opted for using a RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: Given that, you might be stuck with RelativeLayout and constraints defined in C#. The only alternative that might be worth considering if is to add some nesting by defining a layout (StackLayout, RelativeLayout, Grid, whatever) that contains "everything that goes in the top right", and another that contains "everything that goes in the bottom right" then use AbsoluteLayout to get those two container layouts in the right place on the overall page.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for your suggestion!